# Use Freeform to pre-fill a PDF

Tags: plugin-freeform, craft4, pdf

Question says it all I think. We have a freeform form, where a visitor writes down their name and other info. From there a PDF is mailed back to them, and they have some fields to complete, that they've already completed on the form.

Could it be possible to complete a PDF file based on information sent via Freeform ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Freeform has native functionality for this, but it’s doable with a custom plugin or module.

You'd listen to a Freeform submission event, then grab the contents of the form submission you're interested in, then using use something like https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf to actually generate the PDF when those contents.